# Get which control raise event using HTTP Module

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, httpmodule

How I can determine which control in a page clicked using Http Modules?Consider we have a page with 3 button.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you can get access to `HttpContext.Current.Request` then you should check the `Form['__EVENTTARGET']` element to see which control has caused the postback. This however will not work for regular buttons because they are rendered as simple `<input type="submit">`. Luckily they are added as part of the post data so you can iterate over the Form elements and the button you find (by its ID) is the button that caused the postback.