# Audit trail for specific controls in presentation layer

Tags: c#, asp.net, audit-trail

I have a project using ASP.NET with a MS SQL DB, using LINQ classes and require change tracking / audit trail for specific fields. Since the project is quite big, adding the audit-trail functionality manually would be cumbersome. Also, tracking ALL changes on the data-layer would not be perfect (since I also have to handle external data, coming from JSON files sent by HTTP POST, and more ...).

My idea is to implement the usual audit-trail functionality (which is discussed and shown in various other questions/tutorials and should not be the issue here) by extending the existing ASP.NET controls (such as asp:TextBox, asp:CheckBox, asp:DropDownList, etc) with a simple property "bool auditTrail", which can be set to TRUE in my .aspx-file and then tracks the changes in code-behind. This functionality would simply speaking just store the origin page, element #ID, old + new value, logged user and timestamp.

Can this be done - more or less easily? To be honest I am quite firm in ASP.NET but not-so-firm when it comes to extending existing classes. Or maybe the whole idea has a big flaw and you can point me to the right direction? I found solutions using NHibernate, but, if possible, I would prefer to avoid external dependencies.

Thanks for your input!

---

To clarify what I would like, some (pseudo)code. Of course the tagprefix of the controls needs to be set accordingly etc (since I don't think that I can override the asp:WebControl classes themselves ... can I?)

**page.aspx**

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tb1" audit="true"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddl1" audit="true"></asp:DropDownList>
```

**page.aspx.cs**

```
no further code regarding the 2 controls...
```

**AuditControls.cs**

```
public class TextBox : System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox
{
    public bool Audit { get; set; }
}

public class DropDownList : System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList
{
    public bool Audit { get; set; }

}
```

So long, that's the raw outline of what I would like to have in my application. What's missing is how I could - in a solution as generic as possible - add the functionality for the audit trail itself. Storing the value when the Control is rendered (/filled with data), and also retrieving the value history of the Control in order to maybe show it in another (popup-) element. Maybe it's even a good idea to load the data in a seperate element:

**page.aspx**

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tb1" audit="true"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:MyHistoryViewer runat="server" ID="history_tb1" TargetID="tb1" />
```

**AuditControls.cs**

```
public class MyHistoryViewer
{
  public string TargetID {get;set;}
  // program logic to retrieve the value history of the control with ID=TargetID from DB
  // render it as a, let's say HTML table...
}
```

And finally, in order to store all changed values, some sort of "invisible" ChangeTracker could be sitting on the .aspx page, having his eye on all my Controls with property audit set to true. This Changetracker will fire once the page gets a Postback, checking if the current WebControl field values (be it TextBox/DropDownList/...) is different to the latest value. If not, it writes the data to the DB...?

Thinking out loud - any suggestions or hints, do you have experience with this? Any better way to do things?

Answer (score 0):

Also "Thinking out loud"... I'm thinking that the controls you suggested in your question are server controls. this means that on selecting/clicking they will produce a postback. @konrad_pe can I suggest that perhaps a HttpModule would be a good idea to tackle your problem? since HttpModules are hit for every request you could query the form data for the control that caused the request and take it from there.

I read similar here:
[Get which control...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9175838/get-which-control-raise-event-using-http-module)

I hope this gives you another point of view and you find it interesting enough to explore. Good luck!

Comment: Yes the controls are serverside, and yes, they would produce a postback. As I would have several "tracked" controls on one page every now and then, there would be various controls with changes if I postback that page. I'm not sure how HttpModules work, but I will take a look at them and give them a shot.

Thanks for your suggestion!